# Debugging a Qt app by Qt Creator with a Docker development environment

Tags: c++, docker, qt, containers, qt-creator

#### Background

I was using a laptop with openSUSE Leap 15.1 to develop a Qt app. I upgraded to openSUSE Tumbleweed. Now I realize that library versions which my app is dependent upon are *not* available for Tumbleweed. Now I have these options:

1. Reinstall openSUSE Leap 15.1 (or maybe 15.2?)
2. Set up a development environment with some Docker images
3. Set up a development environment with a virtual machine
4. Unavailable dependencies: grab their binary packages directly and install them manually on openSUSE Tumbleweed
5. ...?

#### Question

About 2nd option i.e. Docker.

It's known how to use Docker to deploy the app. You set up the development container with all the dependencies and run some deployment scripts with it.

However, I don't know:

Is it possible to set up Docker containers in a way that Qt Creator **debugger** can be used for development? If I use Docker, would I be able to step through the code with Qt Creator **debugger**?

Comment: A virtual machine, running the older version of SUSE but also including a full display environment, might be a better match.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks! I'm also taking a look at this, but I don't quite get it: https://www.qt.io/blog/docker-builds-from-qtcreator

Comment: @DavidMaze I posted a plan which I'm not sure about. Am I missing something by any chance? I'm going to test it =)

Answer (score 0):

Is this scenario possible:

1. Pull an openSUSE Leap 15.1 Docker image
2. Set up a bindmount volume that links the `/usr/lib64/` directory from inside the container to the `~/leaplib` directory on the host machine. It means `~/leaplib:/usr/lib64/`
3. Do the same for development headers i.e. `~/leapinclude:/usr/include/`
4. Bindmount procedure is explained [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host)
5. Install all the Qt project dependencies on the openSUSE Leap 15.1 container
6. Therefore, all dependency libraries and header files would be installed inside the container bindmount volumes
7. Inside Qt Creator project on the host machine, add `~/leaplib` to library path
8. Inside Qt Creator project on the host machine, add `~/leapinclude` to include path
9. The Qt project source code repository is of course on the host machine
10. Use Qt Creator to open project repository source code
11. You should be able to develop and debug the code with Qt Creator **debugger**, right?

The above plan is *not* tested yet. Not sure if it would work. Any idea? Am I missing something?

Comment: The bind-mount volume will hide everything that was already present in those container directories.  If you mount an empty directory over `/usr/lib64` it's highly likely that whatever the main container process is won't start.

Comment: If you know that you need some set of software preinstalled then it'd be much better to do it in a Dockerfile, than to try to use volumes to persist the changes.

Comment: @DavidMaze If dependency packages are installed inside `/usr/local/lib64/`, then bindmount volume might work. Right?

Comment: @DavidMaze [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169908/158683) provides a method to possibly install dependency packages inside `/usr/local/lib64/`.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the `Dockerfile` hint. I'm studying `Dockerfile`...

Comment: @DavidMaze I have posted another plan with `Dockerfile` =) I'm going to try it...

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario:

1. Make use of `docker-compose` and `Dockerfile` suggested by @DavidMaze
2. Create a `docker-compose.yml` file defining custom bindmount volumes to be able to share data between container and the host
3. Create a `Dockerfile` starting with `FROM opensuse/leap:15.1`
4. Install all the dependency packages inside `Dockerfile` with `zypper --root /usr/local/`
5. Needed container data would be inside `/usr/local/lib64/`, `/usr/local/lib/` and `/usr/local/include/`
6. Share needed container data with the host by copying data to custom bindmount volumes defined inside `docker-compose.yml` file
7. Add bindmount volumes to Qt Creator library path and include path
8. Use Qt Creator to debug the source code in the host machine

Is something missed?